# fetch 10 records with two set of groups with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch 10 records using mysql where 5 records have gender=male and 5 records have gender=female with id DESC.

Should i need two seprate queries for this ?

```
SELECT *  FROM `users` where gender='male' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
SELECT *  FROM `users` where gender='female' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: you can use `union` to combine these two queries

Comment: Writing a query in MySQL that uses aggregate functions to return the top *n* rows in each aggregate is possible, but difficult. So, for gender you'll do well with the UNION.  If you want the top five rows in each postcode ... harder.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *  FROM `users` where gender='male' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
union
SELECT *  FROM `users` where gender='female' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Would return 5 users ordered by ID that are male and 5 users ordered by ID that are female resulting in 10 records total.

Is that what you're after?

Comment: Well, obviously that would result in a syntax error. But yeah, right idea.